# Mocha as library in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

We have all our ui tests written in mocha stored in db. It would be very convenient if can use mocha as a library and run those tests from expressjs. I have searched for this online and only reference I could find is [Mocha as library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692807/mocha-as-a-library) which is more than 2 years old. Moreover the link given in answer is broken in it.

The way I want to run my tests is that when ever a call is made to my express, it should run the tests and update the status in db. I feel being able to use Mocha as library would be  much cleaner approach for my usecase. I am able to runt he tests from commandline with

```
$ $EDITOR test/test.js

var assert = require("assert")
describe('Array', function(){
  describe('#indexOf()', function(){
    it('should return -1 when the value is not present', function(){
      assert.equal(-1, [1,2,3].indexOf(5));
      assert.equal(-1, [1,2,3].indexOf(0));
    })
  })
})

$  mocha

  .

  ✔ 1 test complete (1ms)
```

Comment: See this page for a start: https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/wiki/Using-mocha-programmatically